# Electron <webview>.getWebContents().on('login',..) only called once

Tags: node.js, webview, proxy, electron

I'm trying to use a proxy on a webview element, but when I try to change proxy after it have already been set, it won't call "login" and use the same credentials provided for the proxy the first time.

code:

```
newWebView.getWebContents().on('login', (event, request, authInfo, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (authInfo.isProxy) {
        console.log("Proxy set")
        callback(username, password)
    }
});
```

But the code is only called once.

I'm even initaliziting a new webview element and setting new "login" event but it is still not getting fired.

My though is that because the ip has the same port and ip it will stay to default credentials, but I need to change the auth credentials for the proxy in the webview..

How would this be done?

Comment: Your Electron version is?

Answer (score 0):

app's `login` event will be emitted when `webContents` wants to do basic auth.

```
  const { app } = require('electron')
  app.on("login", (event, webContents, request, authInfo, cb) =>
    tryProxyLogin(webContents, event, request, authInfo, cb)
  );

   /**
   *
   * @param {Electron.webContents} webContents
   * @param {Electron.Event} event
   * @param {Electron.Request} request
   * @param {Electron.AuthInfo} authInfo
   * @param {(username:string,password:string)=>void} cb
   */
  const tryProxyLogin = (webContents, event, request, authInfo, cb) => {
    try {
      const contentId = webContents.id;

      const { username, password } = {
        username: XXXXX,
        password: XXXXX
      };

      if (authInfo.isProxy && username && password) {

        //temp solution about this issue
        //https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16010

        if (!authInfo.realm) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            webContents.reload();
          }, 500);
          return;
        }

        const { country, sessionId } = {
            country: 'XXXXX',
            sessionID: 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
        };

        if (country && sessionId) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.debug(
            "proxy ready to login",
            `customer-${username}-cc-${country}-sessid-${sessionId}`
          );

          cb(
            `customer-${username}-cc-${country}-sessid-${sessionId}-${Date.now()}`,
            password
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

This is based on Electron v4.2.0